# driver.quit() is not working when ignoring IE protected mode setting using code

Tags: python, selenium, closures, settings, mode

Friends,

I would like my program to ignore IE protected mode settings in my code, so written program as below.
Issue is - when using this 'ignore protected mode settings' code in the program, driver.quit() is not working. Browser is not closing down. When i not using this ignore protected mode settings code and set all zones in IE options same (unticked Enable Protect Mode in Security and in Advanced option), then driver.quit() is working and browser is closed down.

Any idea why driver.quit() is not working with below code of ignore protected mode settings?
(Please note - driver.close() also not working).

My code is:

```
if (self.browser=='IE'):

       ie_options = Options()
       ie_options.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True
       driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path='C:/Sel/Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe',options=ie_options)

       print("Browser is Invoked")
       #driver.implicitly_wait(10)
       driver.get("http://www.amazon.co.uk")
       driver.quit()
```